# I cannot insert a bar chart in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint, charts

In rerence to a previous post I too can no longer insert a chart into powerpoint.  When I select chart type it allows me to click but then blinks at me and does nothing.  My IT guys have looked into it and cannot find a solution.  we have conducted a repair on microsoft office but the problem persists.  I am using windows 8.1 and offoice 13.  Any clues please?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What previous post are you referring to? It is better to add your details here rather than refer to another post we have to go look at.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create the chart in excel and copy it over to PowerPoint. Also I'd try to see if you can edit a powerpoint file with a bar chart that has been created on another machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:
★ Run you PowerPoint as administrator.
★ Go to > File > Options > Advanced > Display section - tick both options (disable hardware graphic acceleration; disable slide show hardware graphic acceleration) > reboot your PC.
★ Now open Excel apps tab and then open PowerPoint.
Go to insert tab of PowerPoint and click on chart try two times then see if it inserts charts.